# Swift retain text field content in UIPageViewController while swiping

Tags: swift, uitextfield, swipe, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController with multiple pages. Each contains some text fields. Now my problem: When I type in a value into the text field and swipe between the different pages, the text I entered is removed. Does anyone have an idea how to retain the text?

Comment: missing save after the insert?

Comment: Are you creating a new view controller instance each time the user navigates to another page? Try using the debugger to check the contents of `UIPageViewController`'s `viewControllers` property at different stages to see if the actual view controller instances are different.

Comment: Yes I´m creating new instances each time. When I swipe one page forward and back again, the text is still there, but when swiping two or more pages content of the textfields is gone...

Answer (score 0):

```
let textFieldData = texField.text
```

Carry texFieldData with you when you transfer pages

When you get back to that page:

```
if let text = textFieldData {
   textField.text = text
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Where should I implement it? It doesn´t work in the PageViewContentViewController´s delegate methods...